# New badges are obscuring hats

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, winterbash

Here's what profile pages are meant to look like during the 2015 Winter Bash, with a woolly hat over the corner of the badges box:

[image: DVK]

But I've just earned a new badge, and now the badges box is hiding the woolly hat:

[image: me]

Looks like a bug in the Winter Bash user profile coding, but also one that'd be easy to fix.

**Hat count must be visible at all times!** Who cares about badges when there are hats to be had?

Comment: Why not post this on Meta.SE? This is almost certainly network-wide

Comment: Actually, here's [one good reason not to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271286/congratulations-thanks-to-your-efforts-you-have-earned-box-appears-on-top-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now: ["Congratulations! Thanks to your efforts you have earned" box appears on top of the hat picker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271286/congratulations-thanks-to-your-efforts-you-have-earned-box-appears-on-top-of/271553#271553)

Comment: Excellent, thank you!